# Does Microsoft TFS come with Git

Tags: git, tfs

Does Microsoft TFS come with Git installed or does it have to be separately installed?

Our client has just installed TFS on a server but I need it to have Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes :) TFS (from TFS 2015) comes with GIT.

You can create a GIT repository from TFS, the TFS is like every GIT server (pull, push, commit, clone, pull request etc.).

How to create a new GIT repository from the TFS web portal:

- Navigate to your project by browsing to https://.visualstudio.com and selecting the name of your project. You can select it from the All projects list, or from the Recent projects list if you have accessed it recently.
  [image]
- In the Project area in the web portal, select Code, then select the drop-down next to the current repo name and choose New Repository.
  [image]
- In the Create a new repository dialog, verify that Git is the repo type and enter a name for your new repo. You can also choose to add a README and create a .gitignore for the type of code you plan to manage in the repo. A README contains information about the code in your repo, and a .gitignore file tells Git which types of files to ignore, such as temporary build files from your development environment.
  [image]